# Android - Best way to use colors from JSON file

Tags: android, json, xml, android-resources

I'm working on an app that will retrieve a **colors.json** file from server. This file will have the following structure:

```
[
    {"ServerActionButton.background.normal":
        { "red": 29, "green": 188, "blue": 189, "alpha":255}
    },
    {"ServerActionButton.background.disabled": 
        { "red": 164, "green": 228, "blue": 229, "alpha":255}
    },
    {"ServerActionButton.title.normal": 
        { "red": 255, "green": 255, "blue": 255, "alpha":255}
    },
    ...
]
```

**This JSON should be retrieved on app startup, and I should be able to use these colors throughout the whole app.**

Question: What's the best way to do this? I've thought about the following options:

- Generating a resource XML file from the JSON (it would be great, but is it possible?).
- Mapping the JSON to a model, and then storing it in SharedPreferences.
- Building a local database with the data retrieved from the JSON.

Which would be the best approach? Is there some other possibility I'm not considering?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your use of these colors??

Comment: I need to use them in my layouts.

Comment: Howmany data you have ??

Comment: The app is intended to be used always online. However, I think the best way would be to call the colors service just once (at startup).

Comment: And Howmany json color data you want to store ?

Comment: I think there won't be more than 100 colors.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a more hierarchical structure:

```
[
    {
        "item" : "ServerActionButton",
        "styles" : {
            "normal" :
                          {
                             "title" :      "#FFFFFFFF",
                             "background" : "#FF1DBCBD"
                          },

             "disabled" : {
                             "title" :      "#FF7F7F7F",
                             "background" : "#FF1DBCBD"
                          }
         }
    },

    ...
]
```

Then that's easily parsed into a map (or a map of maps)

```
class StyleProperties
{
    public Color title;
    public Color background;
}



HashMap<String, HashMap<String, StyleProperties>> stylemappings = YourFunctionToParseTheJson(strJson);
```

And then you can easily apply styles to elements as follows:

```
void ApplyStylesToView(View v, String item, String style)
{
    StyleProperty styleProp = null;

     HashMap<String, StyleProperties> stylePropertiesForItem = stylemappings.get("item");

     if (stylePropertiesForItem != null)
     {
          styleProp = stylePropertiesForItem.get(style);

          v.setBackgroundColor(styleProp.background);

          // if the item is a textview, apply the title color
          TextView tv = v as TextView;
          if (v instanceof TextView)
          {
              ((TextView)v).setTextColor(styleProp.title);
          }
     }
}
```